# Determining sets using basic operations

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let A={ O, {O}, 1, a, cat, {1, a, cat}} where O has been used to represent the null set. Determine the follwing:
(a)  A \ {a, b, c} = {O,{O}, 1, cat, {1, a, cat}}
(b) AU{X}= {O,{O}, 1, a, cat, {1, a, cat}, X}
(c) An{cat, dog, mouse} = {cat}
(d) A\O= {{O}, 1, a, cat, {1, a, cat}}
(e) A{O} = {O, 1, a, cat, {1, a, cat}}

Can you please tell me if my answers are right, this was meant to be an easy exercise but I am worried there might be some tricks in there.

Comment: What does $A\{a,b,c\}$ even mean?

Comment: The set A which contains elements a, b and c

Comment: But $A$ does *not* contain $a,b$ and $c$. You already defined what $A$ is.

Comment: That's like saying that $x=2$ and then saying $x_3$ is the number $x$ which is greater than $3$. It makes no sense.

Comment: It's a typo it's meant to say A\{a,b,c}

Comment: On this site, it is usual that you accept and upvote the answer that was helpful to you. That way, the matter can be considered closed.

Answer (score 0):

The answers for $d$ and $e$ are incorrect.

Remember, $A\setminus \emptyset$ is composed of all elements which **are** in $A$ and are **not** in $\setminus$.

Likewise, $A\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ contains all elements that *are* in $A$ and *are not* in $\{\emptyset\}$.

Comment: @Jennifer No. Try to slowly read through my comment. Then, for every element of $A$, ask yourself: "is this an element of $A\setminus \emptyset$?" Then tell me for which elements you answered "no", and why.

Comment: So there is nothing in the null set, so does that mean that it will contain every element of A?

Comment: @Jennifer Precisely! Now, what about the answer to $e$?

Comment: It would also be every element of A?

Comment: @Jennifer No. There is one element in $A$ which is also in $\{\emptyset\}$.

Comment: Thank you so much that makes so much sense to me now. I just re read your answer again for the thenth time and it clicked! Part e is missing {O}

Comment: @Jennifer My pleasure. On this site, it is usual that you accept and upvote the answer that was helpful to you. That way, the matter can be considered closed.